# Continuously running a MySQL query (in a C# program) to find newly added records

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have a program written in C# that takes the result set of a MySQL query and converts the column values to be part of an HTML string in a webrequest. It works great, but I need to be able to continuously run this program and grab only the records that were not grabbed previously so I am not sending the same data over and over. Is there a way to do this in MySQL/C#? The query I'm working with does not have a timestamp.

edit: code:

```
public class mysqlExporter
{
    public mysqlExporter()
    {
        //Create MySQL connection
        string SQLString;
        SQLString = "my connection string";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(SQLString);

        //Write Query
        MySqlDataAdapter eQuery = new MySqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT * FROM whatever;", conn);

        //Put SQL results into dataset
        DataSet eExport = new DataSet();
        eQuery.FillSchema(eExport, SchemaType.Source);
        eQuery.Fill(eExport);

        //Convert dataset to datatable
        DataTable exportTable;
        exportTable = eExport.Tables[0];

        //Make a webrequest for each record
        foreach (DataRow row in exportTable.Rows)
        {

            //Push each record out
            WebRequest httpPost = WebRequest.Create("http://whatever.whatever/name="+row["name"]+"&phone="+row["phone"]);
            httpPost.Method = "POST";
            string postData = httpPost.ToString();
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            httpPost.ContentLength = postData.Length;
            Stream dataStream = httpPost.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();
            WebResponse response = httpPost.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Would be better if we see your work..

Comment: Then give the records a timestamp and you have a clean solution...

Comment: Show us what you did to achieve this, we cant read your mind !

Comment: Alternatively, maintain a list of the IDs you have already sent, only retrieve records not in your list on next request.

Answer (score 0):

just pass the index/primary key (may be auto incremented) value with ur results to the c#, 
then in your request pass the last received index so the query can read from next index

there should be a primary key, just work with that :D